# UWP Enter key press not detected

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, keyup

I am trying to detect key presses in my c# uwp application but the enter key press event is not being triggered. I have added the KeyUp event to the main window and the event is triggered for all keyboard keys except for the enter and space bar keys. Any ideas on how to detect the enter key? The line I added to detect key presses in the XAML in the  tags is KeyUp="MainPg_KeyUp"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`KeyDown` event will not trigger system handled keys. You will have to use `PreviewKeyDown` event.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.previewkeydown

```
<TextBox PreviewKeyDown="eventhandler"/>

 private void eventhandler(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     if(e.Key == VirtualKey.Enter)
     {
     }
 }
```

Comment: I've found that this does work initially but if I then click on a button in the UI the enter key then just does whatever I clicked on. Any ideas why?

Comment: @PeterC - it is a "routed event". The focused element (in your case, the button) gets first chance to handle the event. Sounds like you attached to something higher in the visual tree, but the button "consumed" the event before it got to you.

Answer (score 1):

I would use Keyboard Accelerators. For example, I want to invoke a button click when the user hits the Enter key. The code would be:

```
<Button Content="Invoke Me!">
    <Button.KeyboardAccelerators>
        <KeyboardAccelerator Key="Enter" />
    </Button.KeyboardAccelerators>
</Button>
```

You can also use modifiers like alt, ctrl, or shift as well as the key like so:

```
<Button Content="Save">
    <Button.KeyboardAccelerators>
        <KeyboardAccelerator Key="S" Modifiers="Control" />
    </Button.KeyboardAccelerators>
</Button>
```

You can place these on the page level as well, but you will have to place an event handler in the code behind. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/keyboard-accelerators) is more information about key board acceleration.

Comment: I just tried this and it works but if I then click on a button in the UI the enter key then just does whatever I clicked on. Any ideas why?